# Set the prohibition on editing the field in Ext.window.Window provided

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs

I need to set a ban on editing the text field in Ext.window.Window, provided that the value of the drop-down list is set to Postponed.

I'm trying to do this in the filterCombo function with:

```
var inp = this.up ('window'). down ('# MyTextField');

inp.disable ();
```

but in the console I get the error:
TypeError: this.up is not a function

What am I doing wrong?
Below is my code:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['order', 'id', 'name'],
            storeId: 'DoubleBookStore',
            data : [
                {"id": 23, name: "New", order_install: 1},
                {"id": 24, name: "In Work", order_install: 2},
                {"id": 29, name: "Postponed", order_install: 3},
                {"id": 34, name: "Shipped", order_install: 4},
                {"id": 31, name: "In_transit", order_install: 5}
            ]
        });

function filterCombo(combobox, records) {
    if(records.data.name == 'Postponed'){
      var inp = this.up('window').down('#MyTextField');
      console.log(inp); 
      inp.disable();
    }
    index = records.data.order_install;
    store = combobox.getStore();
    store.clearFilter();

    store.filterBy(
                function(record) {
                    if ((record.internalId == index - 1) || (record.internalId == index) || (record.internalId == index + 1)) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            );
};

var window = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Приложение',
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    items:[{
                xtype: 'combobox',
                fieldLabel: 'Status',
                name: 'status',
                store: store,
                valueField: 'id',
                displayField: 'name',
                typeAhead: true,
                queryMode: 'local',
                value: 24,
                listeners: {
                select : function(combo, records) {
                    filterCombo(combo, records);
                    }
                }

            },
            {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Ваше имя:',
                        itemId:'MyTextField',
                        name: 'name'
            }]
});
window.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
function filterCombo(combobox, records) {
    if (records.data.name == 'Postponed'){
        var inp = combobox.up('window').getComponent('MyTextField');
        console.log(inp);
        inp.disable();
    }
    ...
});
```

**Explanation:**

What you want to do is to get reference to your `textfield` and then disable it.

- your `texfield` config uses `itemId`, so you must use texfield's container `getComponent()` method
- to get `textfield` container use `combobox.up('window')`, not `this.up('window')`

Comment: Thank you so much.
Where can I read about the methods that can be used to obtain different containers?

Comment: @Ambasador ExtJS documentation https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/ is the starting point. One useful article: http://lessgeneric.com/extjs-tutorials/finding-components-dom-elements-or-whatever/.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use "this" outside the scope of the select function, you are already passing "this" as the parameter "combobox", so use it like this:

```
function filterCombo(combobox, records) {

    var inp = combobox.up('window').down('#MyTextField');

    if(records.data.name == 'Postponed'){
      inp.disable();
    } else {
      inp.enable();    
    }
    ...
```

Comment: When I did as you advised me, I get an error: TypeError: inp is null

Answer (score 1):

When you define the filterCombo method as you define it takes this as global scope. Thats why there is no this.up as this here is global.

To make your code working you need to pass the scope when calling your function, just replace

```
    listeners: {
            select : function(combo, records) {
                filterCombo(combo, records);
                }
            }
```

with

```
    listeners: {
            select : function(combo, records) {
                filterCombo.apply(this,[combo, records]);
                }
            }
```

Notice the use of apply to alter the behavior of this in your method.

Comment: When I did as you advised me, I get an error TypeError: inp is null. I output to console this object in filterCombo function and it exists. I think that the problem is in: var inp = combobox.up ('window'). down ('# MyTextField');

Comment: Check this working code https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2lcn

Comment: Thank you so much.Your answer helped me a lot